# MongoDB - Memory leak Issue in Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, mongodb-java

I am running a java project and use mongodb as the back end DB. Here I am getting the following warning everytime I run the web application

```
SEVERE: The web application [/Padua] appears to have started a thread named [MongoCleaner576026458]     but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 29, 2014 11:41:14 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
```

I got to know that this error is because of mongoclient not closed properly. But I am making sure I am closing the connection in every instance

The following is my coding

```
public class DBUtils {
MongoClient mongoClient;
DB db;
DBCollection messages;
DBCollection customerDetails;
public MongoClient connectToDB(String dBName){
    try {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("XX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA" , 27017 );
        db = mongoClient.getDB(dBName);
        db.createCollection("A", null);
        db.createCollection("B", null);         
        db.createCollection("C", null); 
        BasicDBObject msgindexobj = new BasicDBObject();
        msgindexobj.put("processedword", 1);
        msgindexobj.put("mobileID", 1);
        db.getCollection("Messages").ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("location", "2dsphere"), "geospatial");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mongoClient;
}


public void disConnectFromDB(MongoClient mongoclient){
    if (mongoclient!=null){
        mongoclient.close();
        mongoclient=null;
    }       
}
}
```

And I am calling this type of code to access DB

```
DBUtils dbUtils=new DBUtils();
      mongoclient= dbUtils.connectToDB("pingpong");
      DB db = mongoclient.getDB("pingpong");
dbUtils.disConnectFromDB(mongoclient);
```

Am I doing something wrong here....Please help me in resolving this issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The method connectToDB should be public static synchronized. The MongoClient needs to be static, too. Furthermore, you should check if there is already an instance of MongoClient and return this, if necessary. Synchronized modifier applies for disConnectFromDB, too. And you might simply want to call this.mongoclient.close() instead of using the parameter referring to the same singleton instance. This may already solve your problem.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - Thanks a lot for the info. I will implement as per your suggestion. Can you please let me know how to find whether there is a memory leak wrt mongoclient  after this implementation as I am planning to port the code to prod. Thanks

Comment: You have to investigate this. With the code changes I suggested, you only make sure that MongoClient is a singleton.

Comment: Thanks. i have made changes as per your suggestion. I will observe it for a couple of days. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - Thanks for your input. This resolved my issue. I am not seeing any more issues wrt memory leak. Once again thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Please post your comment as a proper answer to the question.